# Weird pie charts on R using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart

I am a beginner in R. I am struggling to represent some of my data as a pie chart. The pie chart is not circular, but rather comprised of sectors of different lenghts (or radius). Sorry if this is unclear.

Here is my code :

```r
ggplot(data, aes(x=Effects)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="count") + 
  coord_polar("x") + 
  xlab("Type of effects") + 
  ylab("Number of references") + 
  ggtitle("Numbers of references by type of effect ")
```

The pie chart I'm getting:
[image: The pie chart I'm getting]

The bar chart from which I draw the pie chart:
[image: The bar chart from which I draw the pie chart]

Comment: Hard to identify the problem without the code. I would guess the problem is in ```stat = "count"```. Make a column with the final count and use ```stat = "identity"```

Answer (score 0):

you probably want a code like this, first one we count the frequency manually and then use `stat="identity"`the second example will use the help of factor to count. The `x=1` helps to stack it on the same place when we use `coord_polar`.

```r
mtcars %>%
  # Count manually
  dplyr::count(cyl) %>%
  # ggplot2
  ggplot(aes(x = 1, y = n, fill = as.factor(cyl))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_polar("y")

# Use count of Factor
mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = 1, fill = as.factor(cyl))) +
  geom_bar() +
  coord_polar("y")
```

Good resource on ggplot2 graphs: https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/piechart-ggplot2.html

[image: pie chart]

Cheers
Hannes